# Excel 2007 VBA RegEx Help Needed

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel 2007 VBA project that my client wants done yesterday and I need to use RegEx to locate strings within some pretty challenging data.  This is my first exposure to RegEx so I'm stuck doing something I think is simple (maybe not) and I'm clueless.

I've added the reference to the VBScript RegEx engine (5.5) and RegEx is working O.K. in Excel - I just don't know how to construct the pattern statement.  I need to locate occurrences of the word "trust" in a range of cells on a worksheet.  In some of my data this word has been abbreviated "Tr".  I have constructed the following RegEx statement to locate the word "trust" and all words that start with a space and contain "tr".

```
"trust| tr"
```

Unfortuantely, this matches any word that contains "tr", like "trail", "tree", and so on.  What I want to match is " tr" - meaning it has a leading space, the "tr", and nothing else in the word.  Can somebody tell me what I need to do to make this happen?

I'm also going to need RegEx patterns for street addresses, city, state, and zip plus last name and first name.  If there's a resource someone can point me to for these expressions I'd appreciate the help.  I'm sorry to ask the group this question without spending the proper amount of time educating myself, by this is a time-sensitive project for which I need your expertise.

Thanks In Advance -

PS - Here a sample of data that I'm working with.  I have this type of data present in 5 columns over 4,000 rows.

```
Jones Family **Trust**
3420 E Ave of the Ftns
3420 E Avenue of the Fountain
320 E ARROWHEAD **TRAILHEAD**
501 S 29TH ST
PO BOX 13422
71343 W Paradise Dr
152035 S 29TH ST
124 Owl Grove Pl
Johnson **Tr**
1900 E Arrowhead **Trl**
1900 E ARROWHEAD **TRL**
```

This is a sample from a column that predominantly contains street addresses.  Other columns contain client names without addresses.  So not every cell contains data that starts with a number.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what some of your sample input might look like and what you would expect to capture from it? Is there a single word on each line? Knowing these details can affect how the expression is built.

Comment: I just tried this pattern `"trust| tr[^a-z]| tr$"` and it seemed to do the trick.  Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: In your sample text `Johnson **Tr**` is not a desired match because `tr` is bracketed by `**`?

Comment: *I'm sorry to ask the group this question without spending the proper amount of time educating myself, by this is a time-sensitive project for which I need your expertise.* If time is of the essence, and you don't know what you don't know, then it's usually time to hire someone.

Comment: @Ro Yo Mi the asterisks were meant to draw attention to what I am trying to match - I wasn't trying to match them.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your expression that finds `trust` and `tr` where they not preceded or followed by a other letters by using the `\b` is a word boundary assertion. `\b` matches at a position that is aptly called a "word boundary".

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
  word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last
  character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string,
  where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

For more information on word boundaries then see also [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). I'm not affiliated with that site.

```
\b(?:trust|tr)\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

After viewing the above, if you're still set on requiring the `tr` preceded by a space, then use this `\b(?:trust|\str)\b`

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/xM4fR9/1

Note: I am assuming you're using the case insensitive flag for this

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    trust                    'trust'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    tr                       'tr'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Or

The `\b(?:trust|tr)\b` expression isn't the most efficient, but it is readable.

A functionally identical, but more efficient regular expression would be:

```
\btr(?:ust)?\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here we're still using the `\b` word boundary, but we've just made the `ust` part of the word `trust` optional with the `(?: ... )?` construct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ro Yo Mi, for the very complete answer.  That's exactly what I needed.